# Calling "[super layoutSubviews]" throws "[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds" exception

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

Whenever i call  [super layoutSubviews]; on my custom UINaivigation bar it throws
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

These are the only two methods im overriding:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 5;
        view.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    [self setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-7 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width , 64);
    return newSize;
}
```

The App is using storyboards and i dynamically add content to the UINavigationBar when a view is loaded but even when i disable this content injection the error is still throw, its would appear to be the act of calling [super layoutSubviews]; which is causing this exception,

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

You can see that all of the items have been positioned properly in the UINavigationBar after the exception as been thrown.

Kind Regards,

Patrick J Quinn.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs...

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a
>   layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior
>   to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your
>   views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method.

You should be using...

```
[super setNeedsLayout];
```

If you need to call it at all, which I doubt you actually do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, ill give that a try (i assume this is called from the view controller and not the overridden nav bar?). The reason the above was done was to re-align the UINavigationBarButtonItems after the nav bar was re-size, otherwise they just anchor to the bottom of the view as though it was the default size :) Thanks.

Comment: Override the function as you have done but just don't use `[super layoutSubviews]` try `[super setNeedsLayout]` instead. It might even work without it.

Comment: Or don't call any super method at all.

Comment: Exactly. That's my thought too. (hence "might not even need it").

Comment: Okay did a bit of testing :) it seems that its not calling super thats the issue, its overriding the layoutSubview method! Removing the super call entirely results in the original problem and calling [super setNeedsLayout];
in the method causes the app to just hang (with no exception or output) on the splash screen. Thanks for the rapid response guys, this is why SO is the greatest community on the planet :)

Comment: Fixed this by moving the layoutSubviews code down to the sizeThatFits method, working perfectly :)